# How can I get an HTML5 data value from a select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use jquery to get an html5 data attribute from a select option?

```
<select id="change-image">
<option value="cool" data-image="myimage.jpg">Cool</option>
</select>

$("#pet-tag-id").change(function() {                    
var src = $("#change-image").data("image");
$("#image-preview").attr("src", src);
});

<img id="image-preview">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

You even did it in the correct manner. jQuery will pull *HTML5 data attributes* into its internal expando *data object* for elements. So you can access them just by name.

The only thing that is incorrect is, that you don't call `.data()` on the correct element. You're calling it on the `<select>`, but you need to grab the selected option element. Like

```
var src = $("#change-image option:selected").data("image");
```

Comment: I'VE BEEN TRYING TO FIGURE OUT SOMETHIING SIMILAR FOR DAAAAAYSSSS!!! DO YOU HEAR ME?! DAAYS!! YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!!!!!! I don't even care if this gets flagged I want you to know how awesome you are.

Comment: I won't flag it, I like it :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#change-image").change(function() {                    
    var data_image = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-image');
});
```

​